# what is wrong with my if -condition?

Tags: regex, r, if-statement, logical-operators, control-flow

So I've been trying to figure out what is wrong with my if-condition, but I am getting nowhere. I am still new to R, so maybe I am not understanding some very basic concept here?

I have a dataframe (dc) to which I appended a column with logical "FALSE". Now I want to change each FALSE into a TRUE based on the values in two columns of dc (dc$Probe and dc$Resp) that I specified using regexpr().

What it does so far is that, for both if-conditions, it changes each FALSE into TRUE regardless of the values in column 5 of dc. When I run the if-conditions seperately, I can see that they seem to be working fine on the OR-part of the condition, meaning the code only generates TRUE when the strings in dc$Probe match one of the strings specified in the OR-part. However, the AND-part seems to be ignored? Thus, when I run the complete code, I get a column with only TRUE, which is not what I want.

Edit: I should get a TRUE only if the string in Probe ends in a certain pattern (as specified in either of the two if conditions I wrote) and if the corresponding value in Resp is a "100" for the patterns specified in my first condition or a "200" for the patterns specified in my second condition. Thus, for strings ending in (sg|s|w1|w3|s1|s2), Resp must be "100" to get a TRUE and for strings ending in (\d\dg|\d\d), Resp must be "200" to get a TRUE. All other cases should be FALSE. For example, if a string ends in s1 and the corresponding value in Resp is 200, the code should return FALSE.

Edit: Some example data:

```
>dc<-data.frame(Subject=rep("SN",6), item.c=(1:6),  Stim=c("XYZc02s03","XYZc01s30","XYZc02s29", "XYZc01s38", "XYZc02s11", "XYZc06w21"), Probe=c("XYzf02s03","XYZf01s30g","XYZf02s29w1","XYZf01s38sg","XYZf02s11s","XYZv06w21s1"), Resp=c(200, 100, 100, 100, 100, 200))
```

This is my code:

```
>dc$Resp<-as.character(dc$Resp) #column 5 in dc
 dc$Probe<-as.character(dc$Probe)

 dc$correct_response <- FALSE

 for (i in 1:nrow(dc)) {
     if (regexpr("^.*sg$", dc$Probe[i])==1 || regexpr("^.*s$", dc$Probe[i])==1 || regexpr("^.*w1$", dc$Probe[i])==1 || regexpr("^.*w3$", dc$Probe[i])==1 || regexpr("^.*s1$", dc$Probe[i])==1 || regexpr("^.*s2$", dc$Probe[i])==1 && dc[i,5]=="100") {(dc$correct_response[i]<- TRUE)}
     if (regexpr("^.*\\d\\dg$", dc$Probe[i])==1 || regexpr("^.*\\d\\d$", dc$Probe[i])==1 && dc[i,5]=="200") {(dc$correct_response[i]<- TRUE)}
}
```

Is there something wrong with the regular expressions I am using? I checked them with glob2rx() and it seems like they are ok...Is my use of  "OR" (||) or/and "AND" (&&) incorrect? How do I implement the AND-part properly? I have also tried the following code for the AND-part, but it didn't change anything:

```
regexpr("200", dc$Resp[i])==1
```

I read the R-help on regular expressions and control flow, but I still don't see what I am doing wrong. Consulting other webpages on logical expressions did not help me either.

Please help!

Comment: @ttmaccer : voila, a little dataframe. I didn't know about dput() yet, but it seems like a useful function. I am going to check that out now..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Im wondering if it can all be reduced to the following:

```
dc<- read.table(header=T,text="Subject item.c      Stim       Probe Resp
      SN      1 XYZc02s03   XYzf02s03  200
      SN      2 XYZc01s30  XYZf01s30g  100
      SN      3 XYZc02s29 XYZf02s29w1  100
      SN      4 XYZc01s38 XYZf01s38sg  100
      SN      5 XYZc02s11  XYZf02s11s  100
      SN      6 XYZc06w21 XYZv06w21s1  200")

cond1<-regexpr("^.*(sg|s|w1|w3|s1|s2)$", dc$Probe)==1 & dc$Resp==100
cond2<-regexpr("^.*(\\d\\dg|\\d\\d)$", dc$Probe)==1 & dc$Resp==200
dc$correct_response<-cond1|cond2
```

Comment: Thanks, your code looks a lot more elegant! Still, this is what I find when I look in line 7358 of my dataframe:   `7358 SN    178 XYZc06w26 XYZv06w26s1  200             TRUE` Now the value here should not be true, as Probe "XYZv06w26s1" ends in s1. What went wrong?

Comment: Either of the two conditions need to be satisfied, not both of them. that is right. However, there needs to be a certain value for Probe AND for Resp in order for that last column to be TRUE. What do you mean by Probe has 2 digits? Probe in line 7358 here ends in s1, so, according to cond1, Resp needs to bee 100 to get TRUE in the last column. But, it gets TRUE even though Resp is 200. Why?

Comment: yes, yes, it is! :) I also missed that typo in your solution. stuff like that is costing me hours of my life... So, your code works perfetcly! Still, I want to educate myself: What is wrong with my code? I mean, other than being overly long and complicated for the task, isn't it the same thing as you did, but in other words?

Comment: omg, it is the BRACKETS!!!! I just wanna hang myself now... OK, thanks a lot for your help, the code looks a lot nicer now. Am I wrong or does this also run faster than my loop?

Answer (score 0):

For one thing, you are missing a logical operator between the 2nd and 3rd clauses of your first `if` statement.

Comment: Thanks, I fixed it. That mistake happened when I copied the code here, in my script it is correct.